# Como solucionar error de hilos con un delegado

Tags: c#, hilos, delegados

Tengo un bucle en el cual una imagen debe de ser invisible durante 20 segundos, y luego de que pasen los 20 segundos la imagen sea visible, pero me da una excepcion.

> 'Operación no válida a través de subprocesos: Se tuvo acceso al control 'pbRecreo' desde un subproceso distinto a aquel en que lo creó.'

Tengo entendido que es con un delegado pero no se bien como hacerlo este es mi código:

```
public delegate void MostrarRecreo(bool visible);

    private void FrmEvaluacion_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        this.pbRecreo.Visible = false;
        Thread ciclo = new Thread(CicloRecreo);
        Listas.hilos.Add(ciclo);
        ciclo.Start();
        

    }
    public void CicloRecreo()
    {
        while (true)
        {
            Thread.Sleep(2000);
            for (int i = 0; i < 1; i++)
            {
                this.pbRecreo.Visible = true; <== excepcion
                Thread.Sleep(5000);
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema es que estás intentando actualizar la UI desde otro thread. La UI solamente puede ser actualizada desde el thread en el que fue creada (main).
Para lidiar con estos problemas, puedes reemplazar:

```
this.pbRecreo.Visible = true;
```

Por el método BeginInvoke del form, el cuál te permitirá actualizar la UI:

```
this.BeginInvoke(new Action(() => this.pbRecreo.Visible = true));
```